# SVN Binaries vs TortoiseSVN

Tags: windows, svn, tortoisesvn

I am setting up SVN for a programming project. I downloaded the binaries, set my PATH variable and can now use SVN from my command line.

After installing a plugin for VS2015 (VisualSVN) it informed me, that i did not install TortoiseSVN and am losing some functionality. I never heard of it so i googled it and it says, that TortoiseSVN is a client that incorporates SVN into the windows explorer.

Now i am kinda confused. Can i work with the binaries only, using the command line (clone repo, commit, push, pull, etc), or do i have to install some kind of enhanced client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command line utilities can do everything you mentioned.  VS2015/VisualSVN is telling you you could have greater integration with the IDE if you had TortoiseSVN installed.  I install them both on my machine.  Sometimes the CLI is better and sometimes the GUI is better depending on what I'm doing.

Comment: Thank you very much. Just a quick question to follow up. Can i use a TortoiseSVN repo with the command line utilities, or does it use an alternative structure / alternative files?

Comment: You can intermix usage of Tortoise and CLI utilities with the same working copy so long as both support the format the working copy is stored in.  If you stick with the newest versions of both you won't have any problem.  You could run into problems if you use a really old CLI with a really new version of Tortoise or vice-versa.